# std::thread class vs std::this_thread namespace in c++?

Tags: c++, multithreading

When we already have a `std::thread` class then why do we require `std::this_thread` namespace?

What are the basic differences between them?

When should i use `std::thread` class and when `std::this_thread` namespace?

Comment: If only there was documentation for these somewhere...

Comment: So I suppose you already read the [reference documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread) you should see it's fundamentally different from the functionality of `std::thread`. Could you be more specific, what's actually unclear for you please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `this_thread` namespace groups functions that access the current thread, so when we need do something on the current thread, we do not need access to the `thread` object of the thread.

The thread class does not provide access for yielding and sleeping, those functions only make sense for the current thread, and can thus be found in the `this_thread` namespace.

If we wish information about a different thread, we need the `thread` instance of that thread, if we need to access the current thread, we can always do that through the functions in the `this_thread` namespace.

The thoughts for using a `this_thread` namespace has also been explained in the draft of the extension:

> **this_thread Namespace**
>
> Note the use of the this_thread namespace to disambiguate when you are requesting the id for the current thread, vs the id of a child thread. The get_id name for this action remains the same in the interest of reducing the conceptual footprint of the interface. This design also applies to the cancellation_requested function:
>
> ```
> std::thread my_child_thread(f);
> typedef std::thread::id ID:
>
> ID my_id std::this_thread::get_id();  // The current thread's id
> ID your_id my_child_thread.get_id();  // The child   thread's id
>
> bool have_i_been_canceled = std::this_thread::cancellation_requested();  // Current thread's cancellation status
> bool have_you_been_canceled = my_child_thread.cancellation_requested();  // Child   thread's cancellation status
> ```

http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2320.html

Adding the functions from the `this_thread` namespace as static members of the `thread` class could have been done, but then the `get_id` function would have to be called something else, to make it clearly distinct from the already existing `get_id` function of the thread class. In other words my guess is that the C++ team decided on adding the functions to a separate namespace to make it more clear that these functions were reading or manipulating the current thread, something that would not have been equally clear had they simply been added as static members of the thread class.

Answer (score 2):

`std::thread` is used to create, monitor and manipulate **new threads**,
`std::this_thread` is used inside **alreay created threads**.

You could have provide `this_thread` as static methods inside a public class inside `std::thread` but this is a design decision,  I'd dare to say that this kind of design is more Java like, where encapsulating the data as a namespace is more C++ - pilosophy tuned kind of design.